# Reading a data file with multiple blocks as one coherent data file

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have a data file that consists of multiple blocks like the following:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2

3 3
4 4
5 5
```

Now let us plot this file:

```
plot "data.dat" w lines
```

The output is two lines, *with a gap* from `x = 2` to `x = 3`. However, if you remove the `\n` in the data file, effectively forming one block, the same command will produce a continuous plot. In a sense, when there are data blocks, gnuplot reads and interprets them separately, leading to independent plots.

**Question:** Is there a way to keep a file's many data blocks and yet have gnuplot read all the blocks in one coherent way, just as if the file was one single data block?

*Clarification:* What I refer to as "data blocks" are the `STATS_blank` in gnuplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little cheat with `awk`:

```
plot "<awk -F'[ ]' '/\\S/ {printf(\"%f %f\\n\",$1,$2)}' <data.dat "  w l
```

will ignore blank lines. (`\S` <=> 'non-whitespace')

**NOTE**

`-F'[ ]'` and `printf` are overinsurances:

```
plot "<awk  '/\\S/ {print $0}' <data.dat "  w l
```

is almost as good as.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @TomSolid's `awk` solution, here is a platform-independent gnuplot-only version.
Simply plot your data `with table` into another datablock, which will remove empty lines.
This will work from gnuplot 5.0.0 on. You can also replace the datablocks with filenames.

**Script:**

```
### remove line break in plot caused by empty lines in datafile
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0
1 1
2 2

3 3
4 4
5 5
EOD

set table $DataNoGap
    plot $Data u 1:2 w table
unset table

set key top left

set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
    
    plot $DataNoGap u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "web-green"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]